# Select data from two tables in Kotlin Anko

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

In my database, there are two tables,

> 1) Task : (id (INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY), title, description, timestamp, category_id(Foreign key of Category -> id ))
>
> 2) Category : (id (INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY), name)

To select data from a table Anko is providing a method like :

```
var mDatabase: DatabaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(activity)
var mResult: List<TaskModel> = ArrayList()
mDatabase.use {
    mResult = select(TABLE_TASK).parseList(classParser())
}
```

What I want is to **show list of task with its category name** 
I have checked all the tutorials and stack links but didn't get any way to achieve this.

**Is there any way to select data from two tables in Kotlin Anko?**

Thanks is Advance!

Comment: [Anko SQLite](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite), like the [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) it builds upon, does not natively support joins. However, Anko doesn't provide a `rawQuery()` mechanism, so you can't even build it yourself...

Comment: @ephemient: This is not true. Anko-SQLite supports native queries!!! See my example here: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/622#issuecomment-388428071

Answer (score 3):

it's late but can be useful for someone like myself

the answer in short is ,Yes

you should create a data class including join column data variables like this:

```
data class joinTable(val id: Int, val title: String, val name:String)
```

and use inner join in select command

```
database.use {
            select("table1 inner join table2",
                    "id,title,name").exec { parseList<joinTable>(classParser()) }
        }
```

that's it

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I have shifted my database to Room.

Comment: your welcome, don't worry , it may be useful for somebody else yet :)

Comment: This did not work for me. I've added another answer how it worked for me using native / raw queries from the SQLiteDatabase class directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my answer for another problem (See https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/622) here, too. I was trying to do a query in Anko SQLite that uses an inner join on two times the same table (e.g. SELECT ... FuelData AS FuelData1 INNER JOIN FuelData AS FuelData2 ON FuelData1.Id = FuelData2.Id).

I added a data class:

```
class FuelData2(
        val id : Int,
        val currentDate: String,
        val litersPer100Km: Double
)
```

and added the logic to my activity class:

```
private fun readFuelData2(): ArrayList<FuelData2> {
    val resultList = ArrayList<FuelData2>()
    val query = "SELECT FuelData1.Id, FuelData2.CurrentDate," +
            " (FuelData2.Fueled / (FuelData2.Mileage - FuelData1.Mileage) * 100) AS LitersPer100Km" +
            " FROM FuelData AS FuelData1" +
            " INNER JOIN FuelData AS FuelData2" +
            " ON FuelData1.Id = (FuelData2.Id - 1);"
    database.use {
        val cursor = database.writableDatabase.rawQuery(query, null)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val fuelData = FuelData2(id = cursor.getInt(0),currentDate = cursor.getString(1),
                    litersPer100Km = cursor.getDouble(2))
            resultList.add(fuelData)
        }
    }
    return resultList
}
```

The query I wanted to do is:

```
SELECT FuelData1.Id, FuelData2.CurrentDate,
(FuelData2.Fueled / (FuelData2.Mileage - FuelData1.Mileage) * 100) AS LitersPer100Km
FROM FuelData AS FuelData1
INNER JOIN FuelData AS FuelData2
ON FuelData1.Id = (FuelData2.Id - 1);
```

I've created another issue for Anko to add one example to the documentation as it's really confusing: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/623